# How can I set the keyboard focus for a QTreeView item?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, focus, pyqt5, qtreeview

I am using python3.5 and PyQt 5.6 with Qt 5.6.1

In my app https://github.com/barry-scott/scm-workbench I have a QTreeView that want to select an item in. I can use the mouse to select an item and the keyboard cursor keys to move relative to the selected item.

But if I use the following to select a specific item at app start up  like this:

```
tree_view = QtWidget.QTreeView()
selection_model = tree_view.selectionModel()
selection_model.select( index,
            selection_model.Clear |
            selection_model.Select |
            selection_model.Current )

tree_view.scrollTo( index )
```

The item represented by index is highlighed in the QTreeView as expected.

But when I press the down cursor key the first item is selected, not the item after the one already selected.

How do I get the keyboard navigation to be relative to the selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setCurrentIndex(modelIndex)` function of the QTreeView should do what you want.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setCurrentIndex

Comment: that worked exactly as I need. It sets hightlight, keyboard focus and scrolls the item into view.